# what is wrong in my coding in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have written a c++ code for a doubly linked list which inserts elements using a for loop and prints the contents of doubly linked list in the format.    (address of previous node)  (data) (address of next node)

[image: output]

as per logic the "prev" address part of second element should contain the next address of first element  ,but it is displaying as different address

for example the next part of first element that is "0" is displayed as 0x3d6838 but the next element "1" s previous address is is displayed as 0x3d10d8.

2.please suggest any change in logic or coding if there anything wrong
[image: code]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. please read this article before asking a question  to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is nothing wrong. `prev` of the second element points to the first element and `next` of the first element points to the second element. They are not supposed to be equal. `prev` of the third element should be equal to `next` of the first, though. And that holds in your output.

Comment: Please, dont post screen-shots of code. Simply insert the code itself into the question. Doing so (0) increases your chances of receiving a useful answer (1) reduces unnecessary use of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Per logic, the prev pointer of second element should display the address of first element and that's exactly what it does. The address of the first element is the same as the next pointer of the beginning of doubly linked list.